# What Does the Verbose Output for 'Wipe' Mean?

Tags: secure-erase

This is in regards to the actual "wipe" command.  I've looked through the man page and not gotten an answer.  I've been unable to find any documentation online which explains what the *verbose* output means.  Does anyone have any insight?

[image]

The above output is from a "quick" wipe (N number of passes with random data). Some files (small in size) wipe relatively quickly so the output lists the total bytes wiped.  But others show a progress which displays [ x / y], where value "x" counts up during each wipe iteration.  And it's unclear what the value of "y" is.  In the above image, "4228" what?  That value remains constant with each iteration. The file in question is about 64MB in size.

The second image here is taken from wiping a copy of the same file, but in "standard" mode, which performs ~34 passes.  In the standard mode, what does the value in parenthesis "(14)" mean?  This value seems to change with each pass.

[image]